# List is modified even when using deepcopy

Tags: python

I'm having an issue copying lists in one of my programs I'm trying to make in Python.

So basically here's the line I'm having trouble with:

```
print(a)
print(b)
a[0]=deepcopy(b[0][-1][0][:1])
print(b)
```

(The prints are just here for debugging purposes, so that I could see how these lists are modified)
And here are what the prints show:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 5], [0, 5, 9, 10]]
[[[[1, 2, 3, 5], [0, 5, 9, 10]]]]
[[[[1], [0, 5, 9, 10]]]]
```

So the issue is that "b" was actually modified though I used a "deepcopy" of it, which makes absolutely no sense to me. 
And this is only happening inside my code, because if you try to run the same lines of codes (by assigning "a" and "b" to what is shown by the prints above just before) it's actually not going to modify "b".
So my question is what could cause a list to be modified when being "deepcopied" ? I didn't put the whole program because it's kind of long and also all the names and comments in it are in french, so I'm just asking for a general answer that could help me understand why this happened.
I hope my explanations were clear enough. Please tell me if they were not and I'll try to explain better =).
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have this struct:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 5], [0, 5, 9, 10]]
b = [[a]]
```

No you change the list of `a`, if you set the list element with a copy or not, is irrelevant.

```
a[0] = [1] # b[0][-1][0][:1]
```

So now `a` is

```
a = [[1], [0, 5, 9, 10]]
```

and `b` is what you printed.

Comment: Oh OK I got it now! Well the only fix I can think about is putting "b=deepcopy(b)" to make b completely independent. Thank's for the help.